# Latest Sticky Posts with Grid Thumbnails for static front page

Tags: sticky-post

i want to make very simple thumbnails grid 4 or 5 images only to show the latest sticky posts with " shortcode to be easy add anywhere "

Thanks!

Comment: And at what point exactly did you get stuck? Please show us your code, make you question as specific as possible. In its current form it is way too broad. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

```
<div class="trending-right">
<?php
 $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' ); // Get all sticky posts
 rsort( $sticky ); // Sort the stickies, latest first
 $sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 6 ); // Number of stickies to show
 query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'caller_get_posts' => 1 ) ); // The query

 if (have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <div class="trend-post">
 <div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100)); ?></div>
 <div class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
 </div>
 <?php endwhile;?>
 <?php } else { echo ""; }
 wp_reset_query();

?>
</div>
```

I used this code inside header.php